# Store Image from JSON into Custom Class iOS

Tags: ios, json, uiimage

I'm building an RSS reader app, following tutorials and what not.

So far I've built a custom class named blogPost, which stores the post name and post author, with a designated initializer based on the name.

I'm attempting to pull the thumbnail image of the post in my for loop, and display it in the cell where I'm currently showing the title and author attributes.

I successfully pulled the image URL and parsed it from JSON but can't seem to store the image in a UIImage.

```
//Custom header for BlogPost

@interface BlogPost : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

// Designated Initializer
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;

+ (id) blogPostWithTitle:(NSString *)tile;
@end
```

And here's the tableViewController

```
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *blogUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wheninmanila.com/api/get_recent_summary/"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogUrl];
NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

self.blogPosts = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray *blogPostsArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in blogPostsArray) {
    BlogPost *blogPost = [BlogPost blogPostWithTitle:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    blogPost.author = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"author"];

    NSURL *thumbURL = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    NSData *thumbData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:thumbURL];

    blogPost.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:thumbData];


    [self.blogPosts addObject:blogPost];
}
```

Comment: The app crashes when I try to run. Kicks out the error [__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
NSURL *thumbURL = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
```

To this:

```
NSURL *thumbURL = [NSURL urlWithString:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];
```

The values in your dictionary will be `NSStrings`, which are not the same thing as `NSURL`'s.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `NSURL` instead of a `NSString` and `NSString` does not respond to selector `isFileURL` (thats why you get the exception). I assume your thumbnail is a string so you should get it as `NSString` and than convert it to `NSURL` as follows :

```
NSString *thumbAsString = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
NSURL *thumbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbAsString];
```